# Deleting User data in firebase Database not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a delete profile button but nothing wants to be deleted in the database!
here are the codes i used for it

```
    private void deleteRecord() {
    DatabaseReference DbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyUsers").child("id");

    Task<Void> mTask = DbRef.getDatabase().getReference("MyUsers").child("id").removeValue();
    mTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            showToastMyUsersDelete("Profile permanently deleted!!");

            Intent i = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this, Login_Activity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            showToastMyUsersDelete("Error Deleting Profile");
        }
    });
}
```

It does what I say but doesn't remove the value If I use this code for example

```
        Task<Void> mTask = DbRef.getDatabase().getReference().removeValue();
```

Then the entire database will be deleted, but really everything!

This is how my hashmap looks not the full one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NINwK.png)

Comment: It is how the json works.  if you have 2 child, so only that specific child deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the id under `MyUsers` is the currently logged in user id, then do the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference DbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyUsers").child(user.getUid());
Task<Void> mTask = DbRef.removeValue();
```

If you don't know the id under `MyUsers` then do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MyUsers");
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo("example@gmail.com").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            data.getRef().removeValue();
                  }
            }
        @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
               }
          });
```

Add a reference to child `MyUsers` then using the query `orderByChild` you can get the correct node and delete it

Comment: This is 100% true thank you very much I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the second code, you are actually storing the reference of the entire database, as you have not specified any particular path. So removeValue() will remove the entire database.